# Why were my comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, specific-question, comments, deleted-comments

I wrote two comments on this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/205362/54237). Both were deleted. The moderators provided no justification for this deletion.  Which "rules" did those comments violate?

---

**Related**

- [Is deleting comments a form of censorship?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/805/54237)

Answer (score 12):

The comments in question stated:

> You: Step zero — pick your ancestors wisely. 
> OP: Can you explain what it means? 
> You: The thinking castes are not merely educated, they are the result of centuries of proper breeding. I would expect most Fields medalists to come from these castes — e.g., Ashkenazim, Brahmins, Parsis, Puritans. After all, MIT is in Boston. However, if one's ancestors lived through an ice age, then they might have been selected for the ability to think and plan long-term, which might be positively correlated with intelligence. Thus, at high latitudes, people might jump from peasant to professor without many generations in between. At lower latitudes, however...

As for why I deleted it, I think that should be obvious. In short: (1) answers in comments always run the risk of being deleted without warning, and (2) your remarks about how “proper breeding” makes those at “high latitudes” inherently more suited to be the “thinking castes” would certainly have derailed the comments section, and likely violate our code of conduct in any case.

Comment: **1.** IMHO, deleting comments that point out that the question is misguided (and should probably be deleted) are exactly the comments that should not be deleted. **2.** If many people cannot deal with biological reality, is that my responsibility? Their parents failed to raise them properly, which is sad, but not exactly my responsibility. Which exact paragraph of the Code of Conduct would that be?

Comment: Your answer does pertain to my 2nd comment. How exactly did my most innocuous 1st comment violate the Code of Conduct?

Comment: Because it's only purpose was as preamble to your second racist comment. OP needed you to clarify it and the clarification was racist, so clearly not "most innocuous".

Comment: If you meant it as satire you should label it as such. Without that, it is pretty offensive.